# Get file from private repo into dockerfile

Tags: docker, drone.io

I currently split my frontend and backend into two separate git repos.

Each repo has a dockerfile that creates an image and publishes it in a private registry.

Now, for the backend repo, I'd like to get the compiled production JS/CSS assets from the frontend image and place them in a folder in my backend repo to serve them.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's the purpose of the frontend image?

Comment: It compiles my frontend JS application into a single `app.js` file that I want to place inside my `/public` folder in my backend repo as my web framework servers static assets from this directory

Comment: I think what Henry meant is that you don't really need a Dockerfile to compile a JS application.

Comment: I know that, but I am using it to avoid having to rebuild the frontend on every backend release. Besides that, I don't see how else I'd get access to the compiled frontend assets in my backend repo during its build